# Union of closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What's $ \displaystyle \bigcup_{n \ge 1}\bigg[\frac{2}{n}, 2+n\bigg]$? I thought it would be $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{2}{n} \le x \le 2+n$ and in particular $\inf(2/n) < x < \sup(2+n) \Rightarrow x \in [0, \infty]$ (wrong). How does one think about something like this?

Comment: $0$ is not in the union. Think geometrically, draw the interval for $n=3$, $n=10$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks! It should be $\inf(2/n) < x < \sup(2+n) \implies x \in (0, \infty) $, right?

Comment: 0 itself isn't in any interval.  The answer is (0,infinity).  For any e > we can find an n such that 2/n < e < 2+n. But we can never find such for 0 or negs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle \bigcup_{n \ge 1}\bigg[\frac{2}{n}, 2+n\bigg] = (0, \infty)$.
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then obviously $[\frac{2}{n}, 2+n] \subset (0, \infty)$, so $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n \ge 1}\bigg[\frac{2}{n}, 2+n\bigg] \subset (0, \infty)$.
On the other hand, let $x \in (0, \infty)$, then $x > 0$, thus you can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $\frac{2}{n} \lt x$ and $2+n \gt x$, so $x \in [\frac{2}{n}, 2+n] \implies (0, \infty) \subset \displaystyle \bigcup_{n \ge 1}\bigg[\frac{2}{n}, 2+n\bigg]$

Comment: Thanks. What's the intuition behind the answer, though? I suppose before the proof you came to the conclusion that it must be $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: The intuition was basically what you did above: taking a look at the limits. $\frac{2}{n}$ goes to zero, the $2+n$ toward $\infty$. The only thing is to realize that "no matter how big your $n$ gets", you can never reach zero.

Comment: And you can (intuitively) think of the union as one interval that's slowly expanding...